# Cannot Connect Kubernetes Secrets to Kubernetes Deployment (Values Are Empty)

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Golang Microservice Application which has following Kubernetes Manifest Configuration...

```yaml
apiVersion: v1 # Service for accessing store application (this) from Ingress...
kind: Service 
metadata:
  name: store-internal-service 
  namespace: store-namespace 
spec:
  type: ClusterIP 
  selector: 
    app: store-internal-service
  ports:
    - name: http 
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000  
  
--- 

apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment 
metadata:
  name: store-application-service
  namespace: store-namespace 
  labels: 
    app: store-application-service

spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:  
      app: store-internal-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: store-internal-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: store-application 
          image: <image>

          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: project-secret-store 
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000 
              protocol: TCP 

          imagePullPolicy: Always
        
          env:
            - name: APPLICATION_PORT
              value: "8000"
            
            - name: APPLICATION_HOST
              value: "localhost"

      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60

--- 

apiVersion: v1 
kind: Secret 
metadata:
  name: project-secret-store
  namespace: store-namespace 

type: Opaque 
stringData:

  # Prometheus Server Credentials... 

  PROMETHEUS_HOST: "prometheus-internal-service"
  PROMETHEUS_PORT: "9090"

  # POSTGRESQL CONFIGURATION.
  DATABASE_HOST: "postgres-internal-service" 
  DATABASE_PORT: "5432" 
  DATABASE_USER: "postgres_user" 
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: "postgres_password" 
  DATABASE_NAME: "store_db"
```

And Also for Test Purposes, I've specified following Variables in order to receive values from secrets in my application..

```golang
var (
    POSTGRES_USER     = os.Getenv("DATABASE_USER")
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD = os.Getenv("DATABASE_PASSWORD")
    POSTGRES_DATABASE = os.Getenv("DATABASE_NAME")
    POSTGRES_HOST     = os.Getenv("DATABASE_HOST")
    POSTGRES_PORT     = os.Getenv("DATABASE_PORT")
)
```

The Problem is when run my application, and after some time go check the logs of my application using `kubectl logs <my-application-pod-name> --namespace=store-namespace`, turns out that all this Golang variables are empty, despite the fact that they all has been declared in the Secret...

There is probably some other issues, that can cause this problem, but if there is some errors in configuration to point out, please share with your thoughts about it :)

Comment: I think you are not using the proper command to check if the environment variables are set. Can you try kubectl exec <pod-name> -- env ?

Comment: I'd also try checking to see if your Go program is correctly seeing the environment variables in a local non-container development setup; something like `DATABASE_HOST=foo go run ./cmd/your-program`.